# Solr collection creation on HDFS failing

Tags: hadoop, solr

I'm trying to run Solr 7.4.0 on Hadoop (I have installed Hadoop 2.7.6 on Windows 10 successfully).
Following Solr user guide I opened file "solrconfig.xml" of _default config and replaced the line

```
<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/>
```

by

```
<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="solr.HdfsDirectoryFactory">
  <str name="solr.hdfs.home">hdfs://localhost:9000/solr</str>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.enabled">true</bool>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.slab.count">1</int>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation">true</bool>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.blocksperbank">16384</int>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.read.enabled">true</bool>
  <bool name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.enable">true</bool>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxmergesizemb">16</int>
  <int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxcachedmb">192</int>
</directoryFactory>
```

I started SolrCloud on HDFS with command line and it run successfully

```
solr start -c -Dsolr.directoryFactory=HdfsDirectoryFactory -Dsolr.lock.type=hdfs -Dsolr.hdfs.home=hdfs://localhost:9000/solr
```

Some arguments as below

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=d:\Project\Java\hadoop-2.7.6\solr-7.4.0\server\tmp
-Djetty.home=d:\Project\Java\hadoop-2.7.6\solr-7.4.0\server
-Djetty.host=0.0.0.0
-Djetty.port=8983
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:d:\Project\Java\hadoop-2.7.6\solr-7.4.0\server\resources\log4j2.xml
-Dsolr.default.confdir=d:\Project\Java\hadoop-2.7.6\solr-7.4.0\server\solr\configsets\_default\conf
-Dsolr.directoryFactory=HdfsDirectoryFactory
-Dsolr.hdfs.home=hdfs://localhost:9000/solr
-Dsolr.install.dir=d:\Project\Java\hadoop-2.7.6\solr-7.4.0
-Dsolr.lock.type=hdfs
-Dsolr.log.dir=d:\Project\Java\hadoop-2.7.6\solr-7.4.0\server\logs
-Dsolr.solr.home=d:\Project\Java\hadoop-2.7.6\solr-7.4.0\server\solr
```

In the next step, I tried to create a collection "Test" by executing this request

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=Test&numShards=1&replicationFactor=1
```

And Solr return an error

```
............
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: hdfs://localhost:9000/solr/Test/core_node2/data\
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPath.resolve(AbstractPath.java:53)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initUpdateLogDir(SolrCore.java:1341)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:923)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:867)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1135)
    ... 45 more
```

Have anyone had the same problem? How can I create a SolrCloud collection and store on Hadoop?

Comment: seems like issue is with slashes could you try to do escaping or something the value for solr.hdfs.home=hdfs://localhost:9000/solr environment variable

Comment: also please share the version with which you are facing the problem so that we could replicate if it is a bug

Comment: I used Solr 7.4.0, Hadoop 2.7.6 installed on windows 10, JDK 1.8.0_181

Comment: could you try P & C around the the slashes in hadoop solr home, I will try it this too once I get time.

Comment: What does "P & C" stands for?

Comment: permutation and combination like to escape the slash of env variables defined.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the below directory factory in solrconfig.xml.

```
<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="solr.HdfsDirectoryFactory">
<str name="solr.hdfs.home">hdfs://namenodeserver:8020/apps/solr</str>
<str name="solr.hdfs.confdir">/etc/hadoop/conf</str>
<str name="solr.hdfs.security.kerberos.enabled">true</str>
<str name="solr.hdfs.security.kerberos.keytabfile">/etc/security/keytabs/solr.service.keytab</str>
<str name="solr.hdfs.security.kerberos.principal">@principal</str>
<bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.enabled">true</bool>
<bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.global">true</bool>
<int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.slab.count">2</int>
<bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation">true</bool>
<int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.blocksperbank">16384</int>
<bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.read.enabled">true</bool>
<bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.write.enabled">false</bool>
<bool name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.enable">true</bool>
<int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxmergesizemb">16</int>
<int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxcachedmb">192</int>
</directoryFactory>
```

upload configs to zookeeper like below.

```
sh /opt/lucidworks-hdpsearch/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh --zkhost hostname1.com,hostname2.com,hostname3.com:2181/solr -cmd upconfig --collection Event --confname webconf --solrhome /home/solr/Event/ --confdir /home/solr/Event/conf
```

Create hdfs collection like below.

```
http://solrhostname:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=Event&numShards=13&replicationFactor=3&maxShardsPerNode=10&instanceDir=hdfs://namenode/apps/solr/Event&config=hdfs://namenode/apps/solr/Event/solrconfig.xml&schema=hdfs://namenode/apps/solr/Event/managed-schema&dataDir=hdfs://namenode/apps/solr/Event/data&collection.configName=webconf
```

Comment: I tried and I failed. Only 2 things my solrconfig.xml differs than yours are kerberos configs (I don't use that) and port 9000 instead 8020 but I don't think they are the cause of the error. I still receive the error: "Illegal char <:> at index 4: hdfs://localhost:9000/solr/Event/core_node2/data"

Comment: Try deleting the hdfs core directories and recreating the collection.

Comment: There are no HDFS directories created because error occurs when SolrCore does initUpdateLogDir, and sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182) throw exception "java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: hdfs://localhost:9000/....." (you can see more stack trace in my question)

Comment: @dennis When I tried also faced the same problem but didn't find any work around.

Comment: I tried on Ubuntu, it worked. So I think the problem was OS.